# Python module not found error, pyCharm keep saying no module name basicconcepts

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming please help me
My project structure is as follows

```
pythonbasics ---- project name
   basicconcepts   --- package one
     __init__.py
     functions.py
   object_oriented  ---package two
     __init__.py
     demo.py
```

I have add function in functions.py in basicconcepts package
in demo.py I'm importing add function as below

```
from basicconcepts.functions import add
add(10, 20)
```

I'm getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/pythonbasics/object_oriented/oops_demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from basicconcepts.functions import add
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basicconcepts'
```

I'm using pyCharm ID. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Hi Surya, I have created the same and verified in my local. It is working. Is it possible to share the entire project on Github or BitBucket in order to identify where the issue is?

Comment: Hi vardin, THanks for the reply I created a Github folder and pushed the project. But this project is little different with the project I mentioned above. In this project also I'm getting same error I added error message screenshot also.
Github url of the project is [link](https://github.com/automationtrainingcenter/packages)